Why interference is happening with two slits but diffraction is happening with one slit?
why interference is happening with two slits but diffraction is happening with one slit? In the case of interference diffraction also happens but not the other way around? Why so?

This has very little to do with physics and just to do with convenient definitions in English. It is simply convenient to have a different word for at least 2 sources interfering.

That's how the two words are defined. One source of radiation (one hole) => the phenomenon of intensity of radiation depending on the angle of scattering is called diffraction. More sources (two holes or slits) => the same phenomenon is called interference (because waves from two or more wave sources interfere).

Related/duplicate? What happens if separation between slits is greater than separation between slits and screen in YDSE experiment?.

@JánLalinský Not to disagree with you but there is "an exception that proves your rule", the diffraction grating.

Feynman on the topic Interference to Diffraction. No one has ever been able to define the difference between interference and diffraction satisfactorily. It is just a question of usage, and there is no specific, important physical difference between them. The best we can do, roughly speaking, is to say that when there are only a few sources, say two, interfering, then the result is usually called interference, but if there is a large number of them, it seems that the word diffraction is more often used.

"Diffraction" and "interference" draw our attention to different aspects of the way waves propagate in space. Underlying both words is the same thing: just waves propagating. When waves propagate then if they are confined to some finite region then they tend to spread out from that region. This aspect of the behaviour we call diffraction. When waves from two or more different places, or travelling in two or more directions, overlap, then their oscillations may add so as to make a bigger oscillation, or so as to cancel each other. This aspect is called interference.
In the case of two slits there is both diffraction as the waves spread from each slit, and also interference as the waves from the different slits overlap.
In the case of a single slit there is diffraction, but there is also some interference as well because the waves from one edge of the slit overlap with those from the other edge. So in this example the diffraction and interference are merged. We normally just use the term "diffraction" in this example, but it's ok to say there is interference as well, as long as you are clear in what you mean. In the end it is just waves moving around, no matter what descriptive words we apply.

Would it be correct so say that both diffraction and interference occur in both the 1 slit and 2 slit experiments, but in each of the experiments only one of the two phenomena is interesting/notable?

yes, but I would express it slightly differently: both phenomena contribute in either experiment, but in each of the experiments only one of the two phenomena is the main thing on show

Each slit spreads light out to produce what is called a diffraction pattern and the light from each of the diffraction patterns overlap which results in an interference pattern.
Usually the separation of the slits is such that the two diffraction patterns cannot be distinguished but if the slit separation is large then two distinct diffraction patterns will be observed and an interference pattern is seen where the diffraction patterns overlap as is shown below.


Diffraction happens in either case. Diffraction in the two-slit case is what makes interference possible. If there was no diffraction, then all you would see on the screen would be one sharply defined image of the slit in the one slit experiment, or two sharply defined, non-overlapping images of the slit in the two slit experiment. If there was no diffraction, then you would not see any evidence of wave-like behavior.

In accordance with @Ohm's Lawman's answer: the premise of your question is wrong: it's too general.
Using units in which $\lambda=1$, diffraction happens when the slit width ($w$) satisfies:
$$ w \ll 1 $$
That leads to a diffraction pattern with width:
$$ \theta_d \approx 1/w $$
and, on the screen at a distance $L$, a spot subtending:
$$ S_d \approx \theta_d L \approx L/w $$
If $ w\gg 1$, you have geometric optics, contradicting your implication that "diffraction happens".
For two slits, you have a separation $d$, and if:
$$ d > w $$
the distance between the fringes will be:
$$ S_i \approx L/d < S_d $$
and you will see a traditional YDSE pattern.
Note that when $d\rightarrow 0$, you recover the single slit pattern with $w' =  2w$, so:
$$ S'_d \rightarrow S_d/2 $$
That is, the image sharpens. If you keep doing this, you recover geometric optics.
The point I'm making here is that a diffraction pattern is an interference pattern, it's just not obvious because there are no peaks.
When we talk about YDSE, we talk about knowing which slit the photon passed through, and if don't know it, we get interference. If we do: there is no interference pattern, but there is still diffraction.
In a single slit diffraction pattern, we don't know which side of the slit the photon went through? Did it go through the left, or the right? Here we are happy saying it went through both, only because they aren't physically separate. But the classical conundrum is the same as when the slits are separate.
If we did know which side it went through, then the inference between the two sides would disappear, and the pattern on the screen would be the incoherent sum of two slits with half the width, so the spot would be:
$$ S_d(w/2) = 2/w = 2S_d $$
That is, it would double in size....just be cause we measured which side of the slit the photon used.
tl;dr It's always a wave, the photon takes all possible paths, there's always an infinte number of paths but we tend to group them into "a slit", knowledge of the path squares the amplitude, lack of knowledge sums amplitudes, and the pattern is the Fourier Transform of the aperture pattern.

Diffraction happens also with wide slits, it happens at any sharp boundary. It's just not very noticeable because there's too much light coming geometrically through the open slit.

well an edge has no length scale, so ofc my approach doesn't apply. But for a wide slit, "geometric optics" means wave properties are "not very noticeable".
